# How can I retrieve facet values from an element range index?

Tags: marklogic

I have created an element range index on some elements. Now I want to show those values as facets. What is an optimized way to get facets from the database?

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the search:search facilities, that already uses all available indexes whenever possible. Add the element as a range constraint, optionally turn off search results. The function should return facets by default if there are constraints defined that can generate facet results.

http://developer.marklogic.com/pubs/5.0/apidocs/SearchAPI.html#search:search

HTH!

Comment: @user1660340 An empty string, that should return facet results for all documents. If you pass in or or more search terms (for example "foo AND bar") then you should see that the facets returned by search:search are limited to those results only.